# Trouble with connection SQL database to JAVA in NetBeans

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, connection

I try to connect netbeans with SQL, but still I have a problem. I suppose, something still  missing.

Here, I create this class:
(Here now errors occurs - on the other hand, I dont really know, if it is fully right)

```
public class connection {
   public Connection con;

   public void dbConnect(){

     try {  
       Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
       String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://FIO\\SQLEXPRESS;" +
           "databaseName=Feedback;integratedSecurity=true";
       con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+ e.toString());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cE) {
        System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+ cE.toString());   
    }

    }
    public Connection getConnection() {
        return con;
    }

    static PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

Then, here within another class named Questions, I try to prepare statement and load information from database:

```
public class Questions {

public void doQuestion()
{...
 ...
 ...
 ...
 connection con = new connection(); 
 con.dbConnect();

 PreparedStatement preparedStatement;


    try{


      **preparedStatement = con.getConnection().createStatement();**


    String sql = "SELECT Answer FROM Feedback.dbo.Question1 WHERE TrainerFirstName=? AND TrainerLastName=?"



    preparedStatement.setString(1,"ffname");

    preparedStatement.setString(2, "llname");

    ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql);


     while(result.next()) 
     {
     System.out.println(result.getString(1) + result.getString(2));
      }


      }catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(Questions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
         ...
          ...
           ...
             ...
              ...
          }
          }
```

Netbeans underlines : `"preparedStatement = con.getConnection().createStatement(); ", due to  "incompatible types: Statement cannot be converted to PreparedStatement."`

I cant overcome it.

Then I try to make something like this to resolve a problem, but problem is still there, even if in different way.:

```
       public class Questions {

         public void doQuestion()

       {...
        ...
         ...
           ...
          connection con = new connection(); 
          con.dbConnect();

          Statement statement;
    try {
        statement = con.getConnection().createStatement();

     String sql = "SELECT Answer FROM Feedback.dbo.Question1 WHERE TrainerFirstName=?      AND TrainerLastName=?"


        **statement.setString(1,"ffname");
        statement.setString(2, "llname");**

        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + rs.getString(2));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Questions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Here, Netbeans underlines 
            "statement.setString(1,"ffname");
             statement.setString(2, "llname");"

due to label:" cannot find symbol
               symbol:method setString(int,String)
               location:variable Statement of type Statement"

Then, I try to send String sql in different form:

```
           String sql = "SELECT Answer FROM Feedback.dbo.Question1 WHERE TrainerFirstName="+ffname+"AND TrainerLastName="+llname
```

And in this way in code omit :
                                 statement.setString(1,"ffname");
                                 statement.setString(2, "llname");

So, code looking something like this:

```
          public class Questions {

         public void doQuestion()

       {...
        ...
         ...
           ...
          connection con = new connection(); 
          con.dbConnect();

          Statement statement;
    try {
        statement = con.getConnection().createStatement();

         String sql = "SELECT Answer FROM Feedback.dbo.Question1 WHERE TrainerFirstName="+ffname+"AND TrainerLastName="+llname


        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + rs.getString(2));
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Questions.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

In this way, everything seems to be O.K., But when I run a project, error appears and points to : " statement = con.getConnection().createStatement(); " and program crashes, of course.

I really dont know what to do.

If anybody has an idea, please write it.

Thank you a lot.

Comment: You need to do `conn.prepareStatement()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this simple example right here i connect to a database and create a statement but i don't use the con.getConnection().createStatement but just con.createStatement() try doing that it could be the problem. I leave you here the whole sql Demo using I database I already had, it could help in the future if you have another problem. Let me know if your problem persists.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
    String dbName = "pc_control";
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String userName = "root";
    String password = "";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM computers");
        while (res.next()) {
            int comp_id = res.getInt("computer_id");
            int emp_id = res.getInt("employee_id");
            String image = res.getString("image");
            String brand = res.getString("brand");
            String model = res.getString("model");
            String m_board = res.getString("m_board");
            String processor = res.getString("processor");
            int ram = res.getInt("ram");
            String hdd = res.getString("hdd");
            String os = res.getString("os");
            String ip_add = res.getString("ip_add");


            System.out.println(comp_id + "\t" + emp_id + "\t" + image + "\t" + brand + "\t" + 
                    model + "\t" + m_board + "\t" + processor + "\t" + ram + "\t" + hdd + "\t" 
                    + os + "\t" + ip_add + "\t");
        }//            
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

Update

well try to redefine your connection class this way or in a way similar to this.

I hope this helps you. and I'm sorry I am sorry I can't point out your error but your implementation of connections is somewhat strange to me.

```
public class MySqlConnection {

static String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
static String dbName = "pc_control";
static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
static String userName = "root";
static String password = "";
static Statement st;
static Connection conn;

public MySqlConnection() {
}

public static boolean connect() {
    try {
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}

public static ResultSet read(String query) 
{
    ResultSet res = null;
    try {
        st = conn.createStatement();
        res = st.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MySqlConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return res;
}

}
```

To make a query simply call the method from any other class this way:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM computers WHERE computer_id= " + id; //or whatever
ResultSet res = MySqlConnection.read(query);
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately I cant remove getConnection();. If I do it, error appers, because of :                                     "cannot find symbol
 symbol:   method createStatement()
 location: variable con of type connection
----:(

Answer (score 0):

this is an example on netbeans of a preparedstament

```
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ptmt = null;

public void add(Archivos archivos) {

    try {
        String query = "INSERT INTO archivosemisor "
                + "(rfcEmisor, cer, llave, password, idError, resultado)"
                + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        con = getConnection();
        ptmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ptmt.setString(1, archivos.getRfcEmisor());
        ptmt.setString(2, archivos.getCer());
        ptmt.setString(3, archivos.getLlave());
        ptmt.setString(4, archivos.getPassword());
        ptmt.setString(5, archivos.getIdError());
        ptmt.setString(6, archivos.getResultado());

        ptmt.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
         .......
    } finally {
            .....
    }

}
```

i hope help you